# PHP doesn't recognise form elements from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, if-statement

HTML: [saucydares.freehostia.com/saucy.php](http://saucydares.freehostia.com/saucy.php) I should just add that while there are no images, the site contains adult themes so isn't work safe.

PHP:

```
    <?php

    mysql_connect("mysql4.freehostia.com", sebsal2_db, "");

    function him()
    {
    $HIMquery = "SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.him UNION SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.other ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
    $HIMresult = mysql_query($HIMquery);
    while ($HIMrow = mysql_fetch_array($HIMresult, MYSQL_NUM)) {echo "$HIMrow[0]";}
    }

    function her()
    {
    $HERquery = "SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.her UNION SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.other ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
    $HERresult = mysql_query($HERquery);
    while ($HERrow = mysql_fetch_array($HERresult, MYSQL_NUM)) {echo "$HERrow[0]";}
    }

    function double()
    {
    $DOUBLEquery = "SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.double ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
    $DOUBLEresult = mysql_query($DOUBLEquery);
    while ($DOUBLErow = mysql_fetch_array($DOUBLEresult, MYSQL_NUM)) {echo "$DOUBLErow[0]";}
    }

    function himlong()
    {
    $HIMLONGquery = "SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.him2 UNION SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.other2 ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
    $HIMLONGresult = mysql_query($HIMLONGquery);
    while ($HIMLONGrow = mysql_fetch_array($HIMLONGresult, MYSQL_NUM)) {echo "$HIMLONGrow[0]";}
    }

    function herlong()
    {
    $HERLONGquery = "SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.her2 UNION SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.other2 ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
    $HERLONGresult = mysql_query($HERLONGquery);
    while ($HERLONGrow = mysql_fetch_array($HERLONGresult, MYSQL_NUM)) {echo "$HERLONGrow[0]";}
    }

    function doublelong()
    {
    $DOUBLELONGquery = "SELECT dares FROM sebsal2_db.double2 ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
    $DOUBLELONGresult = mysql_query($DOUBLELONGquery);
    while ($DOUBLELONGrow = mysql_fetch_array($DOUBLELONGresult, MYSQL_NUM)) {echo "$DOUBLELONGrow[0]";}
    }

var_dump($_POST)

/*    $mode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mode']);
    $player = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['player']);
    echo $player;
    echo $mode;

    if ($player=="For him" && $mode=="Classic Collection") {
    him();
    }

    if ($player=="For her" && $mode=="Classic Collection") {
    her();
    }

    if ($player=="Double dare" && $mode=="Classic Collection") {
    double();
    }

    if ($player=="For him" && $mode=="The Long Game") {
    himlong();
    }

    if ($player=="For her" && $mode=="The Long Game") {
    herlong();
    }

    if ($player=="Double dare" && $mode=="The Long Game") {
    doublelong();
    }
*/
    ?>
```

It is designed to read two drop down lists and display a random field from a mySQL database depending on the combination. Echoing the variables is not permanent, was just a test. Two problems:

- Using var_dump($_POST), if you select
  Classic Collection it sees all the
  options in the right hand box as "For
  him" and if you select The Long Game
  it sees them as "For her".
- For this reason the if statements
  don't work.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: have you tried doing a var_dump($_POST) to see what is actually being submitted?

Comment: See my comment to Mchl's answer -- the issue is the data.php file you are posting the Javascript to.  Whatever is assigning "For him" as the value to `player`, that's the issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you see anything specific? I still can't find it...

Comment: the javascript should be assigning the value based on the dropdown selection. the value is only turned into a variable in php.

Comment: Are you sure that's data.php?  Again, the post value for "player" is set to "her", but that `var_dump` is displaying it as "For her" so there's some transformation happening somewhere.

Comment: Also, before you do the `$.post`, `alert` the values or dump them to the console so you can be sure the Javascript is doing it's thing.

Comment: how can you tell what the post value is set to?

Comment: the problem is in the js! the alerts return as the var_dump does. I've left the code in. I'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: it's fixed - i just changed the way i called the form element to:
var mode = document.forms['form'].elements['mode'].value;
thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Values are 'him','her' not 'For him','For her'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How is that relevant when the variable is based on the selected text as opposed to the values of the options?

Comment: Haha :) You may be on the right lines though as the only bit that doesn't work is the second box.

Comment: No, I think you're on to some Mchl -- because the `var_dump` or whatever it is prints "For him" but the selected value is definitely "her" -- so something is off on the back-end, not the Javascript, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use some serious condensing.  The if statements should be nested, and the functions could be condensed to one function using parameters.  A possible function signature:

```
function game($player, $mode)
```

Then base your business logic and queries inside the function on the parameters.